Seeking alternative approaches: $w = \dfrac{12z}{|z^2|}$ with $|z| = |z - 6 - 6i|.$ Show that $w$ lies on a circle.

$z$ represents all complex numbers such that $|z| = |z - 6 - 6i|.$ The complex number $w$ satisfies $w = \dfrac{12z}{|z^2|}.$ Show that the point representing $w$ on the complex plane $Oxy$ lies on a circle.

Here's a solution that I found:
$w = \dfrac{12z}{|z^2|} \implies w\overline{z} = 12$
$|z| = |z - 6 - 6i| \iff |\overline{z}| = |\overline{z} - 6 + 6i|$
$\implies |w\overline{z}| = |w\overline{z} + (-6 + 6i)w| \iff |(-6 + 6i)w + 12| = 12 \iff |w - 1 - i| = \sqrt{2}$
$\implies$ The point representing $w$ on the complex plane lies on the circle with center $(1, 1)$ and radius $\sqrt{2}.$

On the other hand, I started by showing that the point representing $z$ lies on the line $x + y = 6$. Then I couldn't proceed from $w = \dfrac{12z}{|z^2|} = \dfrac{12(x + yi)}{x^2 + y^2}$. I tried letting $m = \dfrac{12x}{x^2 + y^2}$ and $n =\dfrac{12y}{x^2 + y^2},$ which gives $m^2 + n^2 = \dfrac{12^2}{x^2 + y^2},$ but that doesn't seem to lead to anywhere.
Is it possible to prove it by going in the direction I was taking? I also would like to hear other approaches if they exist. Thank you!

FWIW Inversion gives you the answer in one line, though I'm guessing it's too high-powered for you purposes. $\quad$ $Z$ is a line (perpendicular bisector of those 2 points), and $w$ is inverting $Z$ wrt the origin that is not on $Z$, hence we get a circle.

@CalvinLin Could you clarify what you mean by "inversion"? I think I was overthinking it a little last night as this morning when I'm more clear-minded, I founthat we have $m^2 + n^2 = \dfrac{12^2}{x^2 + y^2}$ and $m + n = \dfrac{12.6}{x^2 + y^2}.$ Divide one expression by another gives $\dfrac{m^2 + n^2}{m + n} = 2,$ which simplifies to a circle equation.

It's a technique. See wikipedia.

@CalvinLin Could you please elaborate on this part "$w$ is inverting $z$ wrt the origin that is not on $z$, hence we get a circle"? Thank you!

If you want to, read up on inversion. FWIW it's overkill for this question.  $\quad$ Inversion maps "circles and lines" into "circles and lines", so we just have to verify that it maps the line Z into the circle W.

The difficulty you're having seems to arise from not actually using the relationship between $x$ and $y$ that restricts $z$ to a line.
If $z = x + yi$ lies on a line satisfying $x + y = 6$, then $z = x + (6-x)i$ for any real $x$.  So
$$|z^2| = |z|^2 = x^2 + (6-x)^2 = 2(x^2 - 6x + 18)$$
and
$$w = \frac{12z}{|z^2|} = \frac{12(x + (6-x)i)}{2(x^2 - 6x + 18)} = \frac{6x}{x^2 - 6x + 18} + \frac{6(6-x)}{x^2 - 6x + 18} i. \tag{1}$$
This corresponds to a parametric equation for a point in the complex plane as a function of a parameter $x$, but without knowing the answer in advance, it is not clear what shape this path describes.
Generally, when we are given a parametric equation $(x(t), y(t))$ for some curve parametrized by $t$ and we are interested in an equivalent implicit equation for this curve, we are motivated to eliminate the parameter $t$ by finding some relationship between $x$ and $y$.  To avoid confusion, we will rename $x$ to $t$ in $(1)$ and name the real component of $w$ as $x$, and the imaginary component of $w$ as $y$:
$$x = \Re(w) = \frac{6t}{t^2 - 6t + 18}, \quad y = \Im(w) = \frac{6(6-t)}{t^2 - 6t + 18}. \tag{2}$$
Now the "game" here is to try to find an equation for $x$ and $y$ that does not include $t$.  One thing we could do is
$$\frac{t^2 - 6t + 18}{6} = \frac{t}{x} = \frac{6-t}{y}.$$  Then cross-multiplying and solving for $t$ gives
$$yt = (6-t)x$$
or
$$t = \frac{6x}{x+y}. \tag{3}$$
Now we can substitute this into either equation in $(2)$ which eliminates $t$.  Let's pick the equation for $x$:
$$x = \frac{6t}{t^2 - 6t + 18} = \frac{6\frac{6x}{x+y}}{\frac{36x^2}{(x+y)^2} - \frac{36x}{x+y} + 18} = \frac{2x(x+y)}{x^2+y^2}. \tag{4}$$
Hence
$$x^2 + y^2 = 2(x+y)$$
or
$$x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2 - 2y + 1 = 2$$
or
$$(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = (\sqrt{2})^2, \tag{5}$$
which we now recognize is the equation of a circle at $(1,1)$ with radius $\sqrt{2}$.

FYI Unique to this setup (so not easily generalizable), notice that $ x^2 + y^2 = \frac{ 12^2 t^2}{(t^2 + (6-t)^2)^2 }  + \frac{ 12^2 (6-t)^2 } { (t^2 + (6-t)^2 ) } = \frac{ 12^2 } { t^2 + (6-t)^2 }  = \frac{ 24 t}{t^2 + (6-t)^2 }  + \frac{ 24 (6-t) } { t^2 + (6-t) } = 2x+2y$.

Hi, thank you very much! You're completely right; I'm not sure why I had two conditions and somehow didn't use one of them last night. I just found a similar strategy like yours this morning but perhaps it avoids a bit of manipulation. I posted it in the comment section under my post. Please let me know if it has any issues. Thank you very much again!

Alternative, simpler but less elegant approach, that may be viewed as a rehabilitation of the $~(x + iy)~$ approach tried by the original poster:
First, setting $~z = x + iy ~: x,y \in \Bbb{R}, ~$ verify the analytical starting point that the set of all satisfying $~z~$ is given by any complex number of the form $~[~x + i(6-x) ~].$
This is done via
$$x^2 + y^2 = (x - 6)^2 + (y - 6)^2 \iff -12(x+y) + 72 = 0.$$
Then, setting $~w = (u + iv) ~: ~u,v \in \Bbb{R},~$ you have that
$$(u + iv) = \frac{12(x + iy)}{| ~[x^2 - y^2] + i[2xy] ~|}. \tag1 $$
The denominator in (1) above may be simplified by noticing that
$$(x^2 - y^2)^2 + (2xy)^2 = (x^2 + y^2)^2.$$
Notice that since $~(x + y) = 6,~$ the denominator of (1) above can never equal $~0.$
Therefore, constraint (1) will be true, if and only if
$$(u + iv) = \frac{12(x + iy)}{x^2 + y^2}. \tag {1.1}$$
So, constraint (1.1) above will be used in place of constraint (1) above.
The next thing to do is to be clear on the goal.  You must find a specific $~z_0 = (x_0 + iy_0) ~: ~x_0,y_0 \in \Bbb{R},~$ and a specific $~r \in \Bbb{R_{\geq 0}},~$ such that whenever constraint (1.1) is satisfied, you also have that
$$| ~(u + iv) - (x_0 + iy_0) ~| = r \iff $$
$$\sqrt{ ~(u - x_0)^2 + (v - y_0)^2 ~} = r 
\iff $$
$$(u - x_0)^2 + (v - y_0)^2 = r^2, \tag2 $$
since both $~(u - x_0)^2~$ and $~(v - y_0)^2~$ are non-negative.
Edit
The contention that $~r~$ may specifically equal $~0,~$ may be regarded as very debatable, given the original problem's use of the word circle.  I leave this possibility in, since it turns out to be harmless to the analysis.

Constraint (1.1) may be assumed to be satisfied, and constraint (2) will be be satisfied if and only if
$$\left( ~\frac{12x}{x^2 + y^2} - x_0 ~\right)^2 + \left( ~\frac{12y}{x^2 + y^2} - y_0 ~\right)^2 = r^2.$$
Set $~(x_1, y_1) = \left( ~\dfrac{x_0}{12}, ~\dfrac{y_0}{12} ~\right),~$ and set $~r_1^2 = \dfrac{r^2}{(12)^2} ~: ~r_1 \geq 0.$
Then, constraint (1.1) may be assumed to be satisfied, and constraint (2) will be be satisfied if and only if
$$\left( ~\frac{12x}{x^2 + y^2} - 12x_1 ~\right)^2 + \left( ~\frac{12y}{x^2 + y^2} - 12y_1 ~\right)^2 = r^2 \iff $$
$$\frac{\left[ ~12x - 12x_1\left(x^2 + y^2\right) ~\right]^2 + \left[ ~12y - 12y_1\left(x^2 + y^2\right) ~\right]^2}{( ~x^2 + y^2 ~)^2} = r^2 \iff $$
$$\left[ ~x - x_1\left(x^2 + y^2\right) ~\right]^2 + \left[ ~y - y_1\left(x^2 + y^2\right) ~\right]^2 = \frac{r^2 (x^2 + y^2)^2}{(12)^2} \iff$$
$$\left[ ~x - x_1\left(x^2 + y^2\right) ~\right]^2 + \left[ ~y - y_1\left(x^2 + y^2\right) ~\right]^2 = r_1^2(x^2 + y^2)^2. \tag{2.1}$$
So, the entire problem has been transformed into finding specific values $~(x_1,y_1)~$ and $~r_1,~$ so that if $~(x + y) = 6,~$ then constraint (2.1) is satisfied.

Assuming that $~(x + y) = 6~$ then

$y~$ becomes $~(6 - x),~$ and

$(x^2 + y^2)~$ becomes $~( ~2x^2 - 12x + 36 ~).$


So, constraint 2.1 becomes
$$[ ~2x^2 - 12x + 36 ~]$$
$$+ [ ~( ~x_1^2 + y_1^2 ~) ~( ~2x^2 - 12x + 36 ~)^2 ~]$$
$$- \left\{ ~[ ~2xx_1 + 2(6-x)y_1 ~] ~[ ~2x^2 - 12x + 36 ~] ~\right\}$$
$$= r_1^2 ~( ~2x^2 - 12x + 36 ~)^2 \iff $$
$$[ (x_1^2 + y_1^2 - r_1^2) ~( ~2x^2 - 12x + 36 ~)^2 $$
$$+ \left\{ ~[ 1 - 2xx_1 - (12 - 2x)y_1 ~] ~[ ~2x^2 - 12x + 36 ~] ~\right\}$$
$$= 0 \iff ~[ ~\text{since} ~x^2 + y^2 \neq 0 ~]$$
$$[ (x_1^2 + y_1^2 - r_1^2) ~( ~2x^2 - 12x + 36 ~) $$
$$= [ 2xx_1 + (12 - 2x)y_1 - 1 ~]. \tag3 $$
To identify $~(x_1,y_1)~$ and $~(r_1),~$ simply interpret constraint (3) above as a 2nd degree polynomial equation in the variable $~x~$ and consider that constraint (3) must hold for all $~x \in \Bbb{R}.~$  Then, see what requirements that this puts on the coefficients of the LHS of the 2nd degree polynomial equation.
Then, constraint (3) above becomes
$$x^2 [ ~2x_1^2 + 2y_1^2 - 2r_1^2 ~]$$
$$+ x[ ~-12(x_1^2 + y_1^2 - r_1^2) + (-2x_1 + 2y_1) ~] $$
$$ + [ ~36(x_1^2 + y_1^2 - r_1^2) + ~(-12y_1 + 1) ~]$$
$$ = 0. \tag4 $$
Since constraint (4) must hold as $~x~$ ranges throughout $~\Bbb{R},~$ you must have that each of the coefficients in the 2nd degree polynomial in $~x~$ is equal to $~0.$
This implies that
$$(x_1^2 + y_1^2 - r_1^2) = 0 \implies $$
$$\left[ ~(x_1 = y_1) ~~\text{and} ~~\left( ~y_1 = \frac{1}{12} ~\right) ~\right] \implies $$
$$x_1 = y_1 = \frac{1}{12} \implies r_1^2 = \frac{2}{(12)^2} \implies $$

$\displaystyle x_0 = 12x_1 = 1.$

$\displaystyle y_0 = 12y_1 = 1.$

$\displaystyle r^2 = (12)^2 r_1^2 = 2 \implies r = \sqrt{2}.$


